# Can 'goog.nullFunction' fit a specific function signature?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure-library, javascript-injection

When some experiment flag is on, I register an injection as :

```
'abcFactory': name.space.createSomeModel
```

and inject the factory as below:

```
/**
 * @param {!function(!Object): !some.DataType} abcFactory
 * @constructor @struct
 */
some.component.do = function(abcFactory) {

};

some.component.do.inject = ['abcFactory'];
```

But when the experiment flag is off, can I just register:

```
'abcFactory': goog.nullFunction
```

without the compiler complaining that the function signature does not match?

Can 'goog.nullFunction' match any function signature? Probably not, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

You could just take make the param nullable (or better yet optional) and only specify the factory function when the flag is on:

https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Annotating-JavaScript-for-the-Closure-Compiler#optional-parameter-in-a-param-annotation

Probably also add some checking to make sure the function is not null before you use it.